# Insert Row doesnt work on OBJ C

Tags: objective-c, json, pagination, ios9

How to fix this code, I try to add another cell at index 0 but there is exception log display

The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10)

```
if([fetchedresult count]>1) {
   for (int i=0; i<[fetchedresult count]; i++) {  
      dataDict = [fetchedresult objectAtIndex:i];
      //Some Code to fill commentResult                     
      commentResult = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:idUserComment,[fieldName ID],image,[fieldName PHOTO],username,[fieldName USERNAME],body,[fieldName BODYCOMMENT],createdAt,[fieldName CREATEDAT], nil];

      [tblComment beginUpdates];
      NSArray *indexPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
      NSArray *lastArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:9 inSection:0]];
      [tblComment deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:lastArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      [dataCommentField insertObject:commentResult atIndex:0];
      [tblComment reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
      [tblComment endUpdates];                    
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @RamonPoca this function triggered in `firstVisibleIndexPath.row==0` i write `[dataCommentField removeAllObjects];` and the exception show  `The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 2 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).` . i just try to figure out how to use pagination in this case, should i use section to do that?

Comment: You have to modify your data source to be coherent with the operations you perform on the table all along. Remove 1 from the datasource, tell the table you removed 1 from the datasource (the table will call the datasource methods to check, so if you return dataCommentField.count it has to be coherent with what you had minus what you removed).

Comment: @RamonPoca Thank You Ramon, i notice i must be use section for each page of comment. I was used the wrong way to get in there. i used `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`then my problem solved.